# Losing focus when changing state inside onFocus event when using custom input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to keep input focus when changing state inside onFocus event
seems like it's not happening with simple input
only when using customInput

```
const CustomInput = ({ onFocus, state }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onFocus={onFocus} />
    </div>
  );
};

const TestInput = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <FilledInput
      inputComponent={(props) => {
        return (
          <CustomInput onFocus={props.onFocus} state={state} />
        );
      }}
      onFocus={() => {
        setState(true);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: what is `FilledInput`?

Comment: Material ui FilledInput